# Environment Variables and Java Hello World

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I used this to at the command line to set create an environment variable for the java compiler:

```
  set path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin
```

Type in `javac` at the command line, it works. I exit from the command line, come back, no longer recognizes `javac` as a command. How can I make it permanent?

While it was working, I linked the compiler and a hello world program:

```
public class HelloWorld { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      System.out.println("Hello, World");
   }
}
```

It creates a class file, what do I do with it?

Note: I am not going to use an IDE until I understand what is going on.

Comment: If you have the Windows Resource Kit you can use SetX. Otherwise, you'll need to set it in the Environment Variables in your "System" control panel. Also, why a 32-bit Java on 64-bit Windows?

Comment: Your problem is about environment variables in Windows. This has nothing to do with programming, or with Java. You would have better luck on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Except for the part where I asked about Java.

Comment: In fact, this question is an exact duplicate of this super user post: http://superuser.com/questions/351459/environment-variable-not-sticking

Comment: As a side note, the `set` command you used will break the command prompt window; it's kind of surprising that javac worked!  Instead of setting the `PATH` to a specific directory, you need to append (or prepend) the directory you want to the existing path: `SET PATH=C:\xxx;%PATH%`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is it works for the current session for the command line. You need to set(or edit) the path variable in the environment variable for the current user or if you happens to be system admin, you can set in the system variables.

check for the Path variable and set it to 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

Answer (score 1):

To make your java path permanent you do this: (note this only works for windows 8 and probably 7 too)
Go to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system configuration > press the button that says environment variables > new > the name is Path and the value C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin.

Now java is in you path permanent.
To run your compiled programm because thats what the .class file is it's your programm.
There are two different options :
1. Open the command prompt 'cmd' navigate to the directory where your .class file is in using the command cd C:....(the rest of your path) and then type in java YourClassName.class.
2. create a new tekst document in the same folder as you .class file and type in ' java YourClassName.class ' then save as > choose all files and name it aName.bat  .
That's it now java is in your path and you can now run your programms.
I hope this was clear enough if not just ask me for clarification.

Comment: I could use some clarification. I get the error: Could not find or load main class .class

Comment: Oh I now see that the site removed something very important from my explination. It is not 'java .class' but 'java HereTheNameOfYourClass.class' hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are several questions here:

"How can I make it permanent?"
Setting environment variables in Windows - answered [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)

"It creates a class file, what do I do with it?"
Is can be run with the command `java`, like:

```
java HelloWorld
```

You should probably read up on Java in general...start [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

First, Compile your file to create an executable.

```
javac example.java
```

This will create your `.class` file along with the .java file you have.

Then, Run your executable.

```
java example
```

This will prompt the message onto the screen.

You can refer to [this](http://www.skylit.com/javamethods/faqs/javaindos.html) link for more. It also shows how to set the environment path, you have problems with.

Comment: The class file is an executable? Why does it have to be linked to Java? What is "Java"?

Comment: Okay. When you install the JDK, you get a JVM or a java virtual machine. It is the JVM which would run the `.class` file.


`.java` is the source code file which contains all your classes and interfaces definitions. Once the `.java` compiles, the compiler(`javac`) then creates the `.class` file, which is nothing but bytecode. This bytecode runs on the JVM and you get the message.

Please read about Java in general. [This](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFE2CE09D83EE3E28) might be a good starting point.